# Totally disconnected implies nowhere dense

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Why is it true that a totally disconnected space implies it is nowhere dense in the reals?

I know that totally disconnected implies the component is a singleton, but how do we construct a nowhere dense set such that their union equals the set itself?

Comment: Are you (i) asking whether "totally disconnected" implies "nowhere dense"; (ii) claiming/asking for a proof that TD implies ND; or (iii) trying to construct a counterexample (i.e., a TD set that is not ND)?

Comment: Hi, I am asking for the proof of it. (ii) It is true from other sources that I have read. :)

Comment: I see. Out of curiosity, what are these sources?

Comment: Where should that totally disconnected space be nowhere dense?

Comment: You should add to the question, that you are talking about being nowhere dense in the set of reals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated, the given proposition is false.

The rationals $\mathbb Q$ is a totally disconnected subset of $\mathbb R$ (essentially because between any two rationals there is an irrational, and if $r$ is irrational, then $( - \infty , r ), (r , + \infty )$ partitions $\mathbb{Q}$ into disjoint nonempty (relatively-)open sets). But far from being nowhere dense, it is actually dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

---

However, a *closed* totally disconnected subset of $\mathbb R$ is nowhere dense. This follows because totally disconnected subsets of $\mathbb R$ cannot include any non-degenerate intervals, and so given $a < b$ as $A \not\supseteq (a,b)$, then $(a,b) \setminus A$ is nonempty open set disjoint from $A$. (Remembering that a set $A$ is nowhere dense if given any nonempty open $U$ there is a nonempty open $V \subseteq U$ disjoint from $A$.)

Comment: @unfru-chikda-uru-wukru is right, the point is that in the book, compactness is assumed as well. Closedess is enough.

Comment: Hi, sorry if it sound trivial, but why does compactness play a part in the proof?

Comment: @user90831: Compactnes implies it's closed, which is needed for the statement to hold. Closed totally disconnected subset of a locally connected space is nowhere dense.

Answer (score 1):

It is as in the proof in the book. The set is totally disconnected, hence it doesn't contain any open interval (since an interval is connected). Since it is closed, it is nowhere dense, dense because open intervals form a base of open sets of reals and a set is nowhere dense iff its closure doesn't contain any nonempty open set.